# Markup-less way to title and link abbrevations/acronyms to glossary entries

Tags: html, xslt, docbook-5, docbook-xsl

Background: I'm writing a DocBook 5 document (and including in it some already-written text) with the intention of generating HTML from it.  I would like to get the semantic markup correct from the beginning so I don't need to re-do it later, but the standard way does not seem to generate what I'm looking for, so I'm not sure if I should deviate from it or not, depending on what is possible with XSL.

Current setup: My glossary only has abbreviated items.  It consists of `glossentry`s each containing a full-spelling `glossterm` and some non-zero amount of `acronym`s and/or `abbrev`s.  I suppose it could all just be `glossterm`s instead.  It doesn't matter to me.  Suppose for example I have this:

```
    <glossentry xml:id="ff"><glossterm>Firefox</glossterm>
        <acronym>FF</acronym>
        <glossdef>
          <para>The web browser made by Mozilla.</para>
        </glossdef>
    </glossentry>
```

### Ideal

Suppose wherever I want to refer to Firefox, I put `FF` in the text.  Ideally, without any additional markup, wherever "FF" (case sensitive) appeared as a plain whole word in a `para`graph (or `title`, but not, for example, `code` or `programlisting` or inside a URL inside an attribute...) in my DocBook file, it would come out in HTML as the text "FF" but marked up as a link to the glossary entry, but not with the standard link CSS, and furthermore with a `title` attribute having the value `Firefox`.  That way a reader can hover to get the acronym/abbreviation spelled out for them, and if that is insufficient, they can click to be taken to a fuller definition.  Meanwhile I would style it black and underlined, so that they know this feature is there, but it doesn't distract one's attention like a normal link does, especially with how often it occurs in the text.

**Main question**: is such replacement of plaintext, markup-less terms even possible in XSL (without creating something like [the Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem))?  If so, can it do this for every `acronym` or `abbrev` found in the glossary, automatically?

I could not figure out how to do this directly, but that is still my goal.  Meanwhile I've tried other things:

### Approach 1

Set up a keyboard macro so I can type `ff` and have that be transformed while I'm typing into `<xref linkend="ff"/>`.

Pros:

1. links to the glossary
2. spells out the abbreviation

Cons:

1. spells out the abbrevation (it would be nice to keep it short to read, not just short to type)...workaround: make the `acronym` into a `glossterm` and put it first in the `glossentry` (loss of semantics, but maybe that's OK here?)
2. links to the glossary (I would like it styled differently)...solution: CSS for `a.xref`
3. even with the above two worked around, the title comes out as `FFFirefox` instead of just `Firefox` (and with others that have more than one synonym, the mashing-together continues)...[solution](http://www.docbook.org/tdg51/en/html/xref.html): put an alternate `xml:id` on your preferred acronym/abbrev, and then make the links in it refer to that id in their `endterm` attribute (as well as the `linkend` referring to the first id)
4. I have to remember to use the keyboard macro rather than just typing and letting the system do the work; any imported text then has to have text replacements done on it for each glossary entry

### Approach 2

Using `<xsl:param name="glossterm.auto.link" select="1"/>` and a keyboard macro to change `FF` into `<glossterm>FF</glossterm>`.

Pros:

1. links to the glossary

Cons:

1. spells out the abbrevation (it would be nice to keep it short to read, not just short to type)...workaround: make the `acronym` into a `glossterm` and put it first in the `glossentry` (loss of semantics, but maybe that's OK here?)
2. links to the glossary (I would like it styled differently)...solution: CSS for `.glossterm`
3. even with the above two worked around, no `title` attribute is given
4. I have to remember to use the keyboard macro rather than just typing and letting the system do the work; any imported text then has to have text replacements done on it for each glossary entry

Approach 1 so far seems better after the workarounds, but is there a way to achieve the ideal I outlined?

Comment: I can't figure out what the context of your question is. If you're asking "can XSLT replace every occurrence of 'FF' in a text node to [something]", the answer is yes. If your question is "can XSLT replace every occurrence of 'FF' *as a word* in a text node to [something]", then the answer is that XSLT 2.0 can do it, but XSLT 1.0 cannot (at least not unless you know in advance all possible word-boundary characters that may appear in text).

Comment: @michael.hor257k, thanks, that's helpful...it's the latter case, because I don't want, e.g., "Hoffman" to be replaced with "HoFirefoxman" (hence my reference to Scunthorpe).  Not only that, I don't want to replace just 'FF', I want it to do this for the contents of every `acronym` or `abbrev` found in the glossary.  Can XSLT 2.0 do that as well?  If so, does it work with DocBook 5?  I'm a total DocBook and XLST newb.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. That's not to say it's a good solution, though. IMHO, wrapping the shortcuts in a markup would be much more robust. -- I am afraid I know nothing about DocBook.