# Multi-`glossterm` `glossentry` getting mashed together in HTML title attribute output

Tags: html, xslt, attributes, docbook, docbook-5

(I'm looking for a workaround for Con 3 of Attempt 1 of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767936/markup-less-way-to-title-and-link-abbrevations-acronyms-to-glossary-entries).)

I have a DocBook 5 doc where some `glossentry` tags contain multiple `glossterm` tags.

The HTML output for `xref` tags having a `linkend` attribute equalling the `xml:id` of a `glossentry` looks good (the link text is the first `glossterm` and the link correctly points to the `glossentry`) except that its mouseover text (in the `title` attribute of the HTML) concatenates all of the `glossterm` texts together.

I would rather it just output the first `glossterm` (or maybe separate the `glossterm`s with `/` or `a.k.a` or something to indicate they're synonyms.)

How would I go about that?  I'm new to DocBook and XSLT.

Comment: Can you show us the XSLT that concatenated them all together?  Also, can you tag this with either xlst-1.0 or xslt-2.0?

Comment: @bjimba, If I knew that, I would know where to start...but I'm a DocBook newb...also I don't know which XSLT is being used here. How can I find out?

Comment: Some people here know XSLT well, but not DocBook. So, can you show a minimal XML where your problem is present? And also show the output it currently generates, and show (with XML, rather than explaining in prose) what's wrong with it. That would help a lot.

Comment: @MathiasMüller the answer you just edited to my other question happens to solve this question as well, even though I intended them in different ways initially.

Comment: Then, either delete this question, or post your own answer to this one and accept it, or let the community close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Do you mean this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869578/docbook-5-rendering-without-abbrev-tag?