# DocBook 5 rendering without abbrev tag

Tags: xslt, rendering, docbook, docbook-5

My DocBook 5 document contains [`glossentry`](http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/glossentry.html) tags that contain `abbrev` tags.  The `abbrev` tags do not seem to contribute anything whatsoever to the rendered HTML.  I'm new to DocBook and XSLT.  Where do I need to start looking to change this?  I've been looking through the docs and aside from being surprised by this apparently being the default behaviour, I'm not sure where to look next to troubleshoot.

**Setup:** My DocBook file starts simply with `<book xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`.  I point `xsltproc` only to a single XSL file, which contains exactly this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet  
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:import href="/usr/share/sgml/docbook/xsl-stylesheets/html/docbook.xsl"/>

<xsl:output method="html"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            indent="no"/>
<xsl:param name="html.stylesheet" select="'main.css'"/>
<xsl:param name="generate.toc">
  book      toc,title
</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="glossentry.show.acronym">yes</xsl:param>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I looked at `docbook-xsl-ns-1.78.1\html\glossary.xsl` and it does have a template `<xsl:template match="d:glossentry/d:abbrev">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:if test="following-sibling::d:acronym|following-sibling::d:abbrev">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>` for `abbrev` elements, based on that I would the content of an `abbrev` element expect to show up, if there are several, to have the contents comma separated. Can you show us a minimal but complete sample of your docbook input, the exact XSLT you use, the HTML you get and the one you want?

Comment: Looking further it seems you can set the parameter `glossentry.show.acronym` to `yes` to ensure that both "This setting controls both acronym and abbrev elements in the glossentry" are displayed.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thanks, I'll add that info (didn't initially because it seems overly detailed questions lately scare people off).  The parameter worked, but it's funny it's in a different format than other ones I've seen!  That threw me at first.

Comment: I understand from your comment that the parameter has solved that problem so I will write an answer about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parameter named `glossentry.show.acronym` that you can set to `yes` to ensure both "`acronym` and `abbrev` elements in the glossentry" are displayed. You can also set it to `primary` to ensure these elements are displayed as the primary text for an entry.

If you need more customization, you would need to add your own template overriding the one in the Docbook stylesheet, which is

```
<xsl:template match="d:glossentry/d:abbrev"> <xsl:apply-templates/> <xsl:if test="following-sibling::d:acronym|following-sibling::d:abbrev">, </xsl:if> </xsl:template>
```

and outputs the `abbrev` elements as a comma separated list.